# How does Micronaut inject with @Inject annotation only?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, javabeans, inject, micronaut

I am using ***@Inject*** in a *Micronaut* project to do **dependency injection via properties**. I started with *ServiceA* which injects *ServiceB* initially, and *ServiceB* has a bunch of its own dependencies, everything seems to be working harmoniously.

```
@Singleton
public class ServiceA {
    @Inject
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Inject
    private ServiceC serviceC;
    
    ...
}
```

```
public class ServiceB {
    @Inject
    private ServiceD serviceD;

    ...
}
```

```
public class ServiceC {
    ...
}
```

The problem came when I added *ServiceC* (which doesn't have any dependencies) to *ServiceA*, the application throws the following exception at runtime.

```
Error processing bean [Definition: ...] method definition [...]: Failed to inject value for field [serviceC] of class: ServiceA

Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [ServiceC] exists.
```

The fix that makes the code compiles and runs again is by adding a ***@Singleton*** to *ServiceC*. By now, the only difference between *ServiceB* and *ServiceC* is that *ServiceB* has got an ***@Inject*** for the class property, whereas *SerivceC* has a ***@Singleton*** annotation for the whole class.

...

Therefore, my questions are: how does *Micronaut* understand how to inject dependencies with only ***@Inject*** annotation in the properties without any class-level annotations like ***@Singleton***, what are the real rules/hierarchy for specifying annotations in *Micronaut*.

Thanks

Comment: Probably because Micronaut defines that a class that has a field/method annotated with `@Inject` is implicitly a bean. --- I would suggest to prefer constructor injection over field injection.

Comment: Yes, agree with preferring constructor injection, but I think the question remains the same if there were no annotation applied to a class that is a dependency to another class. But I am not sure about the implicit behaviour that turns a whole class into a bean

Comment: Aa I said: the CDI container has to analyze the annotations anyhow and thus probably defines that all classes having a field or method annotated with `@Inject` are themselves beans.

Comment: "the CDI container has to analyze the annotations anyhow" - That isn't really true.  Assuming you mean dependency injection (DI) container, the container does not analyze annotations.  We do the DI annotation processing at compile time, before the DI container instance exists.